# Why does Swiss Cheese have holes?

Tags: cheese

I've always enjoyed eating cheese. Just getting that out of the way. I've never quite figured out why Swiss Cheese has holes! I mean, I can understand different shapes like round, square, triangular - though I can't quite fathom why swiss has holes, how they get there, etc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those are called "Eyes" by cheese makers. The appear when bacteria convert lactic acid into propionic acid and carbon dioxide, or metabolise citrate.

These bacteria occur in dairy products, though they can also be added to the curd to get the characteristic eyes. See for example [Propionibacterium freudenreichii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propionibacterium_freudenreichii) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where this myth come from but there are no holes (or really tiny ones) in the majority of Swiss cheese:

Most famous ones :

- [Gruyère](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruy%C3%A8re_%28cheese%29)
- [Vacherin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacherin)
- [Emmental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmental_%28cheese%29) (the only one with holes)
- [Tilsit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilsit_cheese)
- [Appenzeller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appenzeller_%28cheese%29)

Comment: Okay, so I wasn't aware that there were multiple "Swiss Cheese" for the sake of my question we'll go with Emmental which appears to be "Common grocery store swiss cheese"

Comment: Emmental is Swiss Cheese in North America. Just like American Cheese is that horrible bright orange processed nasty stuff even though there are hundreds of different cheeses (such as the wonderful Oka) in North America.

Comment: I visited a Gruyère factory in Switzerland once, the smell is intense.

Comment: Real Gruyere hasn't holes, actually...

Comment: and it's not only Swiss cheeses that have holes. Quality Gouda (hard to find these days even in the Netherlands) and many other Dutch cheeses have holes as well.

Comment: I'm surprised Emmental = Swiss cheese in the US. If I would sell "Swiss cheese" under that name, I would go for a cheaper one which still happens to be Swiss...